# If I get a graduate school interview after accepting a job, do I mention I may need time off for graduate interviews?

Tags: job-offer, education

I have a job interview coming up, and I also applied to five Ph.D programs. I do not know if I will be asked for an interview, but my concern is that I might be offered the job and then have to take time off to do interviews.

With that said, should I mention that in the job interview in the beginning?

I know generally it's not a good idea to mention graduate plans because it makes me seem like a short term candidate, but it also seems bad to not mention anything, get offered the job, and then say "oh by the way, I'm going to need these days off."

Comment: Touche sir. I did apply assuming to be accepted but I think my anxiety is overriding my confidence in being accepted into one of them which is why I feel more concerned about this particular issue.

Comment: People voting to close, did you actually read the question? It DOESN'T ask for advice about what job to take or what skill to learn.

Answer (score 4):

If you are offered the job, or in some cases during the interview, you will be asked "when can you start?" A reasonable reply could be "I am mostly free starting the 13th, however I have some personal commitments I am arranging that will require some time off. I could start on the 13th if I could have occasional unpaid days off for the first month, or I could start in a month if it's important to be there every day once I start."

That said, if you take a job, take a few unpaid days to interview for grad school, and then quit the job within months, it will not reflect well on you. Is this a job that you will only keep until you get into grad school, or is it insurance in case you don't?

Comment: More the latter, I'd like to wait to see if I get in but I'm honestly not sure if I'll be accepted and I don't want to sit idly by and let jobs slip by me and then not get accepted, but it seems like that that might be my only option.